# Server Load 404 in AWS Amplify

Tags: vuejs3, aws-amplify

I have a VUE3 in Typescript App that hosted in AWS Amplify.

CI / CD Setup was Amplify get updates from Github branch and automatically deploy to hosted zone.

It have no issues in localhost.

but in hosted zone it have problem if we open URL https://sub.mydomain.io (example domain)

it's returned this in console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

in

```
https://sub.mydomain.io/js/chunk-vendors.51397126.js
```

and it's show blank screen. but if we add route like https://sub.mydomain.io/login , it's have no issues.

when open to a new window browser also have no issues.

here is the rewrite and redirect setting of the apps:

[image: this is the app setting in Amplify]

what should i do to overcome this situation?